# How can I comply with the terms of the HPND license if I am using a library that contains that license in a commercial application project in python?

Tags: copyright, license

I have a PIL library that is for images in Python. I am developing a desktop program that is for commercial purposes. However, I am not selling, I only offer voluntary donations to users. The PIL library is licensed under [HPND license](https://opensource.org/license/historical-php/). It has some terms that say that without written permission I cannot even use the name of the copyright holder for advertising purposes. It also appears that the copyright notice must appear on all copies of the software.

Well, I don't know if to comply with this in the app I must license my app under the same license, because it asks that I leave a copyright notice on copies of the software. I have checked the library, and a copyright notice appeared in its code. The point is, it asks me to also leave the notice in the software documentation. The license states that I can modify, use, copy for any purpose, free of charge if those conditions are met.

I need help to understand how I can meet those license requirements. Is it required that I leave a file in my source code that says "copyright notice.txt" and it contains the PIL permission notice and its copyright notice? Is that enough to meet those requirements? When compiled into an exe, would the library code need to be duplicated? Do I comply with leaving a copyright notice in the main folder of my desktop app?

Comment: [According to the FSF](https://www.fsf.org/blogs/licensing/historical-permission-notice-and-disclaimer-added-to-license-list), "*The HPND is actually more of a template, allowing developers to select a few options*", so unless you're prepared to name and link to the PIL library in question, it may be difficult to answer this question with any certainty.

Comment: Hello, it is the HPND license, that license has those conditions, that the copyright notice and the permission notice will be in all copies of the software. But they do not explain how these conditions must be met when using the library in desktop applications made in Python. I can't do legal consulting because I don't have any money for lawyers, but I am looking for help with this open source thing.

Comment: @PythonJob134 Pls provide the exact link to the library, because the HPND license contains several optional elements, and we cannot answer unless we know exactly which ones are in or out.